# Angular: How to update html with http get request after using http put request?

Tags: angular, http-get

My html renders a list of cities using a http get request. I want my html to render again when I use a put request to update the list. How would I do this?

Html:

```
<div *ngFor="let city of cityList">
  <h4>{{city}}</h4>
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
cityList: string[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.getCities();
  }

getCities() {
  this.cityListService.getCitiesSaved().subscribe(
    cities => {
      this.cityList = cities;
    }
  );
}
```

Service:

```
currentCityList: string[];

getCitiesSaved(): Observable<string[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.url).map((data: Response) => {
    this.currentCityList = data.json().cityAlerts;
    return data.json().cityAlerts;
  });
}
```

Comment: The exact same way as you have now but put instead of get.... I am not sure exactly what your question is. Where are you stuck? What is your error / problem?

Comment: Angular will automatically update your HTML once you change the contents of `cityList` array. So just update an array after PUT and you'll be set.

Comment: Also `Http` has been deprecated in favor of `HttpClient`, I recommend you use that instead.

Comment: I want my html to update asynchronously without having to call the get request again.

Comment: Just return the changes or the entire list from the `put` and update your component model accordingly. You would do it using the same type of procedures/calls that you are currently doing for `get`

Comment: Thanks everyone I got it working now! I did as you said and updated the cityList array and my server using the put request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular the view is updating dynamically, so all that you need is just to push new elements to `cityList` array and Angular will do the trick.